# how to show portrait image fit into DIV in html tag?

Tags: html, css

i have portrait image and i want to fit in DIV tag with same ratio. 
example image you can find in below link

http://www.megafileupload.com/4Loy/img.png

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @progsource i try this one http://jsbin.com/vikanovaya/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

If want to maintain the DIV height and width and fit the image into the DIV while maintaining the images ratio then your code is already doing this.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9w3fkc5g/) with added border showing how the image won't go any larger as it has already filled the parent DIV height.

If you want to change it so the DIVs height reacts to the images attributes then remove the DIV height and add the following img rule:

```
img {width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

This will fill the parent container width while maintaining the image ratio, and the DIV height will react automatically to fit the image.

Example 2: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o3yjwtcL/1/)

Comment: Second thoughts, is the image an actual example of what you want to achieve? as in do you want the 'Thank you for registering' pop to fill the screen? Let me know if so and I'll amend answer.